# Declaring collection accessor methods in Objective-C necessary?

Tags: objective-c, macos, collections, accessor, kvc

I've got a quickie today. Say I have a class called `BSDHistoryManager`. It's a simple state history recorder like in a web browser (aka a `History` object [`window.history`]). Here are simplified examples of the .h/m files:

**BSDHistoryManager.h**

```
@interface BSDHistoryManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *states;

@end
```

**BSDHistoryManager.m**

```
@implementation BSDHistoryManager {
    NSMutableArray *_states;
}

- (NSArray *)states
{
    return _states.copy;
}

- (void)setStates:(NSArray *)states
{
    if ( [states isEqualToArray:_states] )
        return;
    _states = states.mutableCopy;
}

@end
```

As you can see, I have a standard mutable collection on the inside which is copied when accessed with the getter so the internals don't get messed up. At this point, I want to add some public accessor methods like `-addState:`, `-removeState:`, etc. For example, I like to make my own accessors like this:

```
- (void)addState:(BSDState *)state;
- (void)insertState:(BSDState *)state atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

However, I want to define KVC methods, too. You know, the ones that look like this:

```
- (void)addStatesObject:(id)object;
- (void)insertObject:(id)object inStatesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Now I have both, and that's cool, but I want my class interface to be nice and clean, so it's easier to read and understand. My question is: when implementing the [KVC accessor patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178660), do I need to declare those methods or do I get KVC-compliance "for free" by just implementing the methods? Or a better question is: do I even need to implement the KVC methods if I make my own custom-named ones?

Hopefully this makes sense, but if not, I'll try to explain it a little better. Thanks for reading!

Comment: KVC should come for free but they may not be what you (probably falsely) expect from them. Because your examples of addStatesObject: and isertState:atIndex: don't comply with the KVC pattern.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Do you mean the `-addState:` method?